# string function

Tags: c++

please can anybody explain me what this function do?i am confused

```
bool isOnlyLeftHand(string w) {
    return (w.find_first_not_of("qwertasdfgzxcvb") == string::npos);
}//end isOnlyLeftHand
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Returns true if the string can be entered with the left-hand only (on the keyboard) :)

Comment: except that 'b' is keyed in with the right index finger if you are not already down with several mugs!

Comment: @chubsdad I always use the left index finger to type 'b'

Comment: @Aillyn: http://library.thinkquest.org/18709/data/keys.html. Not sure if we have a standard for this too :)

Comment: @chubs: me too. I'm left handed. And I'm not drunk.

Comment: my initial research says that this is also an 'implementation defined' behavior. And I am not drunk too at least for now!.

Answer (score 2):

This looks for characters that are not any of `qwertasdfgzxcvb` in the string `w`, and returns true if none are found (note the double negation).

In other words, return true if `w` can be typed using the left hand side of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

It is literally checking for characters within the string that would be typed with the left handed.

The code `find_first_not_of` will scan the string and find the first position that is not part of the input `w`

Answer (score 1):

returns true if any character other than those in the quoted string is absent in the input string represented by 'w'.